# Deleted Google Sheets with Project - Can the script still run?

Tags: google-apps-script

When we delete the Google Sheet that contains an Apps Script - does that mean that the Apps script is also deleted and can no longer run? I deleted a spreadsheet which contained the project and cannot seem to find the script now :(

I was under the impression it was associated in the account as I had given the script access to my google Drive?

Thanks!

Comment: I believe if  you have deleted the container that have also deleted all of its contents